# Javascript Update panel call parent function and using ifream

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, updatepanel

Hi have frame  PersoneArama.aspx page in and my function look like this

```
    function KullaniciBilgi(deger) {

        parent.KullaniciAyarKisiBilgi(deger);
    }
```

And i call the this function in KullaniciAyarkari.aspx

```
    function KullaniciAyarKisiBilgi(deger) {

        $('.KullanciAyarlarikulllanciIdHidden').val(deger.split('|')[0]);
        $('.KullaniciAyarTc').val(deger.split('|')[1]);
        $('.KullaniciAyarAd').val(deger.split('|')[2]);
        $('.KullaniciAyarSoyAd').val(deger.split('|')[3]);
        $('#KisiArama').modal('hide');
    }
```

But i using updatepanel firs time this work but second not work i didnt understant that statu .

Comment: KullaniciBilgi fonksiyonunu ne zaman çağırıyorsun ?

Comment: Update panelin içinde çağırıyorum ilk çağırdığımda çalışıyor ikincisinde ise  çalışmıyor frame çağırmıyor.

Comment: // run after postback
function runAfterPostback() {
    //code
}

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(runAfterPostback); şunu bir dene istersen

Comment: olmazsa fonksiyonlarını page_load olayında tekrar tanımlaman gerekebilir

Comment: I try this but didnt work .